# Removing title bar and address bar from pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, css, popupwindow, address-bar

Is there a way to remove title bar and address bar from pop up windows in modern browsers.

I was researching that and always saw that it is only possible if a fullscreen mode is enabled.
And that it is a security issue if removing address bars.

Is that true that we cannot do it?

If we can''t how then can I implement in any other ways?

Thank's

Comment: What purpose will your popup window serve? There is always the modal option in addition to the jqueryui dialog already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a security feature and cannot be disabled. What you can do is use custom dialogs, for example provided by jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/